# Iteration on RDD data Apache Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, iteration, rdd

i have a data looks like below consists of latitude and longitude values

```
45.25,23.45
22.15,19.35
33.24,12.45
15.67,21.22
```

I need to construct a matrix based on Euclidean distance between two points
[image]

as there are 4 points, we will get and 4x4 matrix

```
p1p1 p1p2 p1p3 p1p4
p2p1 p2p2 ........
..................
..........p4p3 p4p4
```

Now the question is how can we perform iterations in Apache Spark java ( as below code which is implemented in java )

```
int nrows = latit.size();
int ncols = longit.size();
double[][] w = new double[nrows][ncols];
for(int i=0;i<nrows;i++) {
       for(int j=0;j<ncols;j++) {
                temp1 = latit.get(i) - latit.get(j);
                temp2 = longit.get(i) - longit.get(j);
                temp3 = Math.pow(temp1, 2) + Math.pow(temp2, 2);
               w[i][j] = Math.sqrt(temp3);
           }
       }
```

Please suggest the suitable way to store data into RDD and performing iterations in Java API

Answer (score 3):

In Spark you would translate this into a set of transformations and actions.
Given `pointsRDD` containing the location data, then you can obtain the euclidean distance as:

```
points.cartesian(points).map{case ((x1, y1),(x2,y2)) => math.sqrt((x2-x1)*(x2-x1)+(y2-y1)*(y2-y1))}
```

Comment: In which RDD format does this above code output would be  (x,y) or x and  if i want to return RDD as single values not as pairs what is the transformation

Comment: @swagath001  Given `RDD[(Double,Double)]` and `f: (Double,Double) => Double`  `rdd.map(f)` will be of type `RDD[Double]`

Comment: I think it is not related to java API ? Can you please post the logic related  to spark-java api

Comment: @swagath001 The Java version is functionally equivalent, but syntax-wise a lot more verbose. Writing this in Java is an exercise left for the reader. This is a starting point: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaRDDLike.html#cartesian